# Ansible variable length command line options

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a directive using `shell` or `command` to execute something that could have any number of command line arguments.

So something like

```
- Name:  Runs MediaWiki command line setup.
  command:  "php /opt/wiki/maintanance/install.php {{ arguments }}"
```

I'm looking for something like a `[item for "%s=%s % (key, value) in arguments"]`

Looking at ansible variables, everything I see there wants to loop each command on any of the datastruture.

Does anyone know what is the best way to join an arbitrary list of arguments for a command and the best way to structure that in a variables file?

Answer (score 1):

If `arguments` is a list you can use the [join filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join).

```
- Name:  Runs MediaWiki command line setup.
  command:  "php /opt/wiki/maintanance/install.php {{ arguments | join }}"
```

If `arguments` is a dict you might be able to do something like this:

```
- Name:  Runs MediaWiki command line setup.
  command:  "php /opt/wiki/maintanance/install.php {{ arguments | urlencode | replace('&', ' ') }}"
```